# Image Reader / Eval / Transformation

Tags: cntk

Reposted here from CNTK Issue #1237 by request

Using: CNTK for Windows v.2.0 Beta 5 GPU

Tutorial: [CNTK 201B: Hands On Labs Image Recognition](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/v2.0.beta7.0/Tutorials/CNTK_201B_CIFAR-10_ImageHandsOn.ipynb)

I have modified the tutorial to train and evaluate B &W .png images. (128H, 128W, 1C)
The post [Evaluate a saved convolutional network](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Evaluate-a-saved-convolutional-network) indicates mean transform and image transpose are required to evaluate the image correctly with the model.

On Nov 18 the tutorial was updated, dropping the transpose in eval(). Now I'm confused. Is transpose required? Has something changed in CNTK to allow it to evaluate .png images loaded using PIL ?

Previously

```
def eval(pred_op, image_path):
    . . . 
    image_data   = np.array(Image.open(image_path), dtype=np.float32).T
```

Comment: Referring to: [Issue 276 Conversion from HWC to CHW](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/CNTK-Evaluate-Image-Transforms#layout-conversion-from-hwc-to-chw)

The post [Evaluate a saved convolutional network](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Evaluate-a-saved-convolutional-network) uses the following to transpose:

pic = np.ascontiguousarray(np.transpose(pic, (2, 0, 1)))

This is not the same as x.T previously given in tutorial 201B giving different results.

I suspect y.transpose(2,0,1) is correct.

Please comment

Comment: So you are saying the transpose was there at some point, and got dropped?

Comment: Btw, in your comment your anchor text talks about "Issue 276", but the link points to a Wiki page, not an issue.

Comment: @Anton S. - Yes the transpose was dropped from Tutorial 201B on Nov, 18 as originally stated.  Apologies on the link.  CNTK Issue 276 is where I found the Link to the Wiki Doc for 'Conversion from HWC to CHW'.

Comment: Then I think I still don't get the issue. If I look at the current state of that tutorial, the `transpose` is there on line 577, [link here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blame/v2.0.beta7.0/Tutorials/CNTK_201B_CIFAR-10_ImageHandsOn.ipynb#L577)

Comment: Yes, it is now correct. Before Nov 18th the tutorial used .T (incorrect) to perform a transpose.  This was removed from the tutorial on the 18th.  After posting this issue (1237) the correct transpose of (2, 0, 1) was added to the tutorial.

Comment: The tutorial now looks correct to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed for an image loaded with PIL the correct thing is

```
img.transpose(2,0,1)
```

You can see the same transformation also in the artistic style transfer  tutorial.